# Application form submitting to database sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: php, sql, insert

This is an application form that submits all fields to a database. Sometimes it works perfect no problems at all, other times everything submits but the uploaded file isn't included, and sometimes nothing at all is entered into the database. I've tried all random test entries and cant figure out what is triggering the failures and cannot see it in my code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10485760)){

        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        } else {
            $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
            $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name

            $uniquename = $timestamp.$file_basename;

            $newfilename = md5($uniquename) . $file_ext;

            if (file_exists("$setting[upload_apps]" . $newfilename)) {
                 echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$setting[upload_apps]" . $newfilename);
                $target_path = "/files/";
                $target_path = $target_path . $newfilename;

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO career_apps (position, email, fname, lname, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, cell, cemployed, layoff, proof, priorapp, appdate, prioremploy, prioremploydate, availdate, convict, convictdetails, school, school_study, school_years, school_degree, college, college_study, college_years, college_degree, grad, grad_study, grad_years, grad_degree, certs, employer1, employer1_address, employer1_telephone, employer1_title, employer1_supervisor, employer1_from, employer1_to, employer1_salary, employer1_duties, employer1_reason, employer2, employer2_address, employer2_telephone, employer2_title, employer2_supervisor, employer2_from, employer2_to, employer2_salary, employer2_duties, employer2_reason, employer3, employer3_address, employer3_telephone, employer3_title, employer3_supervisor, employer3_from, employer3_to, employer3_salary, employer3_duties, employer3_reason, resume_file, resume, sig1, date1, sig2, date2, ip, submitted) VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[address1]', '$_POST[address2]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[state]', '$_POST[zip]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[cell]', '$_POST[cemployed]', '$_POST[layoff]', '$_POST[proof]', '$_POST[priorapp]', '$_POST[appdate]', '$_POST[prioremploy]', ''$_POST[prioremploydate]', '$_POST[availdate]', '$_POST[convict]', '$_POST[convictdetails]', '$_POST[school]', '$_POST[school_study]', '$_POST[school_years]', '$_POST[school_degree]', '$_POST[college]', '$_POST[college_study]', '$_POST[college_years]', '$_POST[college_degree]', '$_POST[grad]', '$_POST[grad_study]', '$_POST[grad_years]', '$_POST[grad_degree]', '$_POST[certs]', '$_POST[employer1]', '$_POST[employer1_address]', '$_POST[employer1_telephone]', '$_POST[employer1_title]', '$_POST[employer1_supervisor]', '$_POST[employer1_from]', '$_POST[employer1_to]', '$_POST[employer1_salary]', '$_POST[employer1_duties]', '$_POST[employer1_reason]', '$_POST[employer2]', '$_POST[employer2_address]', '$_POST[employer2_telephone]', '$_POST[employer2_title]', '$_POST[employer2_supervisor]', '$_POST[employer2_from]', '$_POST[employer2_to]', '$_POST[employer2_salary]', '$_POST[employer2_duties]', '$_POST[employer2_reason]', '$_POST[employer3]', '$_POST[employer3_address]', '$_POST[employer3_telephone]', '$_POST[employer3_title]', '$_POST[employer3_supervisor]', '$_POST[employer3_from]', '$_POST[employer3_to]', '$_POST[employer3_salary]', '$_POST[employer3_duties]', '$_POST[employer3_reason]', '$target_path', '$_POST[resume]', '$_POST[sig1]', '$_POST[date1]', '$_POST[sig2]', '$_POST[date2]', '$ip', '$time')");
                if ($query) {
                echo"<p align='center'><span class='warning'>CONFIRMATION!</span></p>$app_success";
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO career_apps (position, email, fname, lname, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, cell, cemployed, layoff, proof, priorapp, appdate, prioremploy, prioremploydate, availdate, convict, convictdetails, school, school_study, school_years, school_degree, college, college_study, college_years, college_degree, grad, grad_study, grad_years, grad_degree, certs, employer1, employer1_address, employer1_telephone, employer1_title, employer1_supervisor, employer1_from, employer1_to, employer1_salary, employer1_duties, employer1_reason, employer2, employer2_address, employer2_telephone, employer2_title, employer2_supervisor, employer2_from, employer2_to, employer2_salary, employer2_duties, employer2_reason, employer3, employer3_address, employer3_telephone, employer3_title, employer3_supervisor, employer3_from, employer3_to, employer3_salary, employer3_duties, employer3_reason, resume, sig1, date1, sig2, date2, ip, submitted) VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[address1]', '$_POST[address2]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[state]', '$_POST[zip]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[cell]', '$_POST[cemployed]', '$_POST[layoff]', '$_POST[proof]', '$_POST[priorapp]', '$_POST[appdate]', '$_POST[prioremploy]', '$_POST[prioremploydate]', '$_POST[availdate]', '$_POST[convict]', '$_POST[convictdetails]', '$_POST[school]', '$_POST[school_study]', '$_POST[school_years]', '$_POST[school_degree]', '$_POST[college]', '$_POST[college_study]', '$_POST[college_years]', '$_POST[college_degree]', '$_POST[grad]', '$_POST[grad_study]', '$_POST[grad_years]', '$_POST[grad_degree]', '$_POST[certs]', '$_POST[employer1]', '$_POST[employer1_address]', '$_POST[employer1_telephone]', '$_POST[employer1_title]', '$_POST[employer1_supervisor]', '$_POST[employer1_from]', '$_POST[employer1_to]', '$_POST[employer1_salary]', '$_POST[employer1_duties]', '$_POST[employer1_reason]', '$_POST[employer2]', '$_POST[employer2_address]', '$_POST[employer2_telephone]', '$_POST[employer2_title]', '$_POST[employer2_supervisor]', '$_POST[employer2_from]', '$_POST[employer2_to]', '$_POST[employer2_salary]', '$_POST[employer2_duties]', '$_POST[employer2_reason]', '$_POST[employer3]', '$_POST[employer3_address]', '$_POST[employer3_telephone]', '$_POST[employer3_title]', '$_POST[employer3_supervisor]', '$_POST[employer3_from]', '$_POST[employer3_to]', '$_POST[employer3_salary]', '$_POST[employer3_duties]', '$_POST[employer3_reason]', '$_POST[resume]', '$_POST[sig1]', '$_POST[date1]', '$_POST[sig2]', '$_POST[date2]', '$ip', '$time')");
                if ($query) {
                echo"<p align='center'><span class='warning'>CONFIRMATION!</span></p>$app_success";
                }
    }
```

Comment: PHP limits the size of uploaded files. This could be the reason why nothing is sent sometimes, because you simply shows an error over there.

Comment: You're adding information directly from $_POST into the query. That's very bad practice - if nothing else, it will break if someone with the surname `O'Brian` submits the form. You should look at using mysqli or PDO, and bind variables into prepared statements instead.

Comment: do you escape filenames and check the file size limit? To set/get extension it's better to check MIME type. Also check your code against sql injection. employer2.. employerN is really bad database design consider changing it. The last thing, you should use pdo or mysqli, mysql_* functions are depracated.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the helps i will look into these things!

my biggest problem is I inherited this and have very limited experience, and read most of these things as chinese!

Comment: It turns out it was something related to the captcha. after removing the captcha i have had absolutely no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with file size limits. If you add a .htaccess file to your websites route directory you should be able to fix the problem:

```
memory_limit = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

additionally you can change the php.ini file.

http://drupal.org/node/97193

I've used .htaccess in the past because I did not have access to php.ini when I uploaded my site to the host.